# How can I expand rows and conditionally fill new column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame containing info on an infection rate. One column represents the number of individuals sampled and another is the number infected. I would like to expand the data frame so that each row in an individual and fill a new column with 0 for not infected and 1 for infection.
Here is an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Site_Number  = c(1, 1, 1, 2),
                 Population = c(100, 200, 300, 100),
                  Number_Sampled = c(6, 3, 6, 4),
                  Number_Infected = c(0, 1, 5, 1))
```

Which looks like:

```
  Site_Number Population    Number_Sampled  Number_Infected 
           1      100            6                  0  
           2      200            3                  1 
           1      300            6                  5  
           2      100            4                  1
```

Here is the desired output:

```
  Site_Number Population    Infected   
           1      100            0  
           1      100            0
           1      100            0
           1      100            0
           1      100            0
           1      100            0
           2      200            1
           2      200            0
           2      200            0  
           1      300            1 
           1      300            1
           1      300            1
           1      300            1
           1      300            1
           1      300            0                 
           2      100            1
           2      100            0
           2      100            0
           2      100            0
```

I have tried a few variations of `pivot_longer()`, `uncount()`, and others but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  tidyr::uncount(Number_Sampled) |>
  mutate(Infected = 1 * (row_number() <= Number_Infected),
         .by = c(Site_Number, Population))
```

Result

```
   Site_Number Population Number_Infected Infected
1            1        100               0        0
2            1        100               0        0
3            1        100               0        0
4            1        100               0        0
5            1        100               0        0
6            1        100               0        0
7            1        200               1        1
8            1        200               1        0
9            1        200               1        0
10           1        300               5        1
11           1        300               5        1
12           1        300               5        1
13           1        300               5        1
14           1        300               5        1
15           1        300               5        0
16           2        100               1        1
17           2        100               1        0
18           2        100               1        0
19           2        100               1        0
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, you can use `reframe()` by groups.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  reframe(Infected = +(seq_len(Number_Sampled) <= Number_Infected),
          .by = c(Site_Number, Population))

#    Site_Number Population Infected
# 1            1        100        0
# 2            1        100        0
# 3            1        100        0
# 4            1        100        0
# 5            1        100        0
# 6            1        100        0
# 7            1        200        1
# 8            1        200        0
# 9            1        200        0
# 10           1        300        1
# 11           1        300        1
# 12           1        300        1
# 13           1        300        1
# 14           1        300        1
# 15           1        300        0
# 16           2        100        1
# 17           2        100        0
# 18           2        100        0
# 19           2        100        0
```

---

##### `base` solution with `by()`

```r
by(df, ~ Site_Number + Population, \(x) {
  row.names(x) <- NULL
  transform(x, Infected = +(seq_len(Number_Sampled) <= Number_Infected))
}) |> do.call(what = rbind)
```